# how to use SASxport in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using `SASxport` in `knitr` package of R, but it doesn't work.Is there anything wrong? It works well in markdown when I am creating html file. I would like to create a pdf file though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
datapath = '.../test.xpt'
library("SASxport")
eos91.data <- read.xport(datapath)
@
\end{document}
```

There is an error message:

```
Running texi2dvi on test.tex...failed

Error running C:/PROGRA~1/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)
```

The log is here http://pastebin.com/qkZ8Q6Ef

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *please* paste the log to a website where we do not have to wait for 30 seconds to click the download link, and wait for another 30 seconds only to find a link to a suspicious executable `iLividSetupV1.exe`; you can use either Github gist or pastebin.com, which are way way better than the website you used

Comment: I have pasetd it here, hope it works. http://pastebin.com/qkZ8Q6Ef Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Can you provide the tex file as well? Or even better, provide a copy of `test.xpt`. I tried the examples in the `SASxport` package and did not see any problems.